Specmatic test does not send bearer token to server
I'm having a problem trying to test an API contract with Specmatic. The problem is that when I start Specmatic's test mode (started with npm), it does not use the bearer token that I provide for the test. I have tried passing the bearer token through a file (bearer.txt) and through an environment variable (BEARER). I'm using Macos Sonoma 14.4.1 on a MacBook Pro M2.
I have created a PoC proyect to reproduce it. It can be seen in this GitHub public repo: https://github.com/vladimir-bataller-NTT/specmatic-mini-poc
This is my package.json configuration, with the two scripts that I use, start (starts de local server) and test (starts de Specmatic test):
{
  "name": "specmatic-mini-poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Vladimir Bataller",
  "description": "Minimal Express application for testing Rest application with Specmatic",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app",
    "test": "specmatic test --testBaseURL=http://localhost:3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "specmatic": "^1.3.9"
  }
}

Mi mini express application (app.js) is the following:
import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/pets/:id", (req, res) => {
  const token = req.get("Authorization");
  console.log('----->', token);
  if (!token) {
    res.status(403);
    res.send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }
  res.json({
    id: parseInt(req.params.id),
    name: 'Scooby',
    type: 'Golden Retriever',
    status: 'Adopted'
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('EXPRESS STARTED ON PORT 3000'));

This Server implements the following contract, it is provided in the contract.yaml file:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Contract for the petstore service
  version: '1'
paths:
  /pets/{petid}:
    get:
      summary: Should be able to get a pet by petId
      parameters:
        - name: petid
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: number
          examples:
            SCOOBY_200_OK:
              value: 1
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Should be able to get a pet by petId
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                required:
                  - id
                  - name
                  - status
                  - type
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: number
                  name:
                    type: string
                  type:
                    type: string
                  status:
                    type: string
              examples:
                SCOOBY_200_OK:
                  value:
                    id: 1
                    name: Scooby
                    type: Golden Retriever
                    status: Adopted

components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT

security:
  - bearerAuth: []

And the configuration of the Specmatic test is providen by the following specmatic.json file:
{
  "auth": {
    "bearer-file": "bearer.txt"
  },
  "sources": [
    {
      "provider": "filesystem",
      "test": [
        "contract.yaml"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


As can be seen, I provide the bearer token in a file “bearer.txt”. This file contains only the token as plain text, something as this:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

The problem is that when I run the test, npm run test, the Bearer token that Specmatic provides is not the one that I have in the bearer.txt or in an environment variable. Nevertheless it provides something as
Authorization: Bearer JKCKT
As can be seen in the following console output.
specmatic-mini-poc % npm run test

> specmatic-mini-poc@1.0.0 test
> specmatic test --testBaseURL=http://localhost:3000

Loading config file ./specmatic.json

API Specification Summary: ./contract.yaml
  OpenAPI Version: 3.0.1
  API Paths: 1, API Operations: 1
  Schema components: null, Security Schemes: [http]


Endpoints API not found, cannot calculate actual coverage


--------------------
  Request to http://localhost:3000 at 2024-4-10 0:28:57.961
    GET /pets/1
    Authorization: Bearer JKCKT
    Accept-Charset: UTF-8
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: NOT SENT
    
    

  Response at 2024-4-10 0:28:57.963
    200 OK
    X-Powered-By: Express
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 69
    ETag: W/"45-I28b2GsRHCZOFOGiWEH0LQIrPmk"
    Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2024 10:28:57 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5
    
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Scooby",
        "type": "Golden Retriever",
        "status": "Adopted"
    }


 Scenario: GET /pets/(petid:number) -> 200 | EX:SCOOBY_200_OK has SUCCEEDED



Could not load report configuration, coverage will be calculated but no coverage threshold will be enforced

|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| API COVERAGE SUMMARY                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| coverage | path          | method | response | # exercised | remarks |
|----------|---------------|--------|----------|-------------|---------|
|     100% | /pets/{petid} | GET    |      200 |           1 | covered |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 100% API Coverage reported from 1 path                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|



Saving Open API Coverage Report json to ./build/reports/specmatic ...


Tests run: 1, Successes: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0 


Does anybody knows if it is a Specmatic bug or I'm missing some configuration?

I answer myself.
I have seen this ask for help in the GitHub repo of Specmatic:
https://github.com/znsio/specmatic/discussions/913
That tells that only Environment Variable Works now a days. So, for the moment, forget text file with the token.
And in this question, I have realized that the name of the environment variable must be the same as the one that we have assigned to the security scheme in the openapi contract.

So in my example the name of the environment variable should be bearerAuth. Be careful, because it is case sensitive.
So, as a fix, I have changed the test script entry in package.json
"test": "cross-env-file -p ./bearer.json specmatic test --testBaseURL=http://localhost:3000"

I have used cross-env-file for loading the environment variable from a bearer.json file, this file has the following content:
{
    "bearerAuth": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"
}

Note that in that json there is an attribute which name is the name of the environment variable we want to set, and its value is provided.
I have pushed this fix to the repo of the PoC:
https://github.com/vladimir-bataller-NTT/specmatic-mini-poc

Thanks Vladimir. Glad to hear you were able to fix it. Co-founder and CTO of Specmatic here. As you rightly mentioned the bearer token has to be passed through Env variable - https://specmatic.in/documentation/authentication.html#bearer. Please feel free to reach out to us by raising issues / questions on https://github.com/znsio/specmatic/issues also.
